# Scrollbar issue in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having one `table` within a `div`. In button click I'm changing the width of the `table` same as the width of `div`. Problem is in IE11 and Firefox scrollbar doesn't appear whereas in chrome scrolllbar is appearing. I no need that scrollbar in chrome. What's wrong with my code??

[Here is my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/DkSP7/)

Is there any workaround for this issue??

Anyone help me out to do this!!

Comment: do you want it or do you **not** want the scrollbar to appear?

Comment: If you want the scrollbar to always appear, use `overflow-x: scroll`. If you don't want it to appear, use something like `table.width($("#container").width()-1);` I think the most interesting question is why Chrome displays the scrollbar at all.

Comment: @webeno I don't want that scrollbar

Comment: have you tried `overflow:hidden` on `#container`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/DkSP7/3/) to remove scrollbar in google chrome. Issue is that table content width is calculated dynamically (to place columns evenly depending on content) and is not equal to width you define - difference may be less that 1 px, but it's presented.

Fix is to use padding 1px for container or set table width less `table.width(table.width() / 2 - 1)`; I prefer padding value as table width will remain the one you need (1000,500,250,etc.. instead of 999, 499, 249...)

Answer (score 0):

Use window's width:

```
 $("#changeWidth").click(function () {
            var table = $("#sampleTable");
            table.width($(window).width());
        });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DkSP7/1/)

and if you don't need the scrollbar then deduct some value

```
table.width($(window).width() - 20);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DkSP7/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I no need that scrollbar in chrome. I have updated my question. Please see that

Comment: what's your update? use second demo code if you don't need scrollbar

Comment: Is there anyother way without deducting hardcoded value?

Comment: you must deduct the value for your example.